# How do I smooth the action of other objects on a line when i animate one with css?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

So here's my CSS so far.

```css
e.button {
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 14px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: .5em 2em .55em;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
  -moz-border-radius: .5em;
  border-radius: .5em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition: font-size;
}

.button:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  transition: font-size: 2s;
  height: 2em;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.button:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

The html:

```
<div class ="button">Home</div> <div class = "button"> Products</div>
<div class ="button"> Awards</div><div class = "button">Magic</div>
```

Theres no classes or anything on any of the body tags or normal layout ones. While this managed to change the button, it causes chaos every where else.

[Here's a gif showing you what happens.](http://www.gfycat.com/MagnificentGoodnaturedAtlanticridleyturtle)

I'm not exactly looking for a fix, but more or less direction.  Is there a way to stop the other objects on the line from reacting?  Maybe bump them smoothly to the side?

Comment: please share your html too.

Comment: instead of transitioning font-size... transition font. There isn't a need for the colon all you need is a space.

Comment: Somehitng like this? http://jsfiddle.net/rb433x3x/1/

Comment: @dowomenfart (nice name, hah) and yes! that exactly!

Comment: If you do an absolute position on each of the buttons and then z-index, you will be able to keep them in the same place. You'll also be able to make the hovered button overlap the other buttons. Fixed and absolute is really the only way to deal with isolated size transforms, at least that I'm aware of.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte Thanks!  That was my next question.

Comment: as matthew said, you should use absolute position for smoother animation. But I doubt if you'll ever get very smooth text animation that look well with elements' smooth animation.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `scale()` to make the elements bigger on hover. This will prevent each element to move the others on hover :

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 14px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: .5em 2em .55em;
  background: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  border-radius: .5em;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -webkit-transform-origin:50% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin:50% 0;
  transform-origin:50% 0;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s;
  transition: transform .2s;
}
.button:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
.button:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Home</div>
<div class="button">Products</div>
<div class="button">Awards</div>
<div class="button">Magic</div>
```

Note that I also set the transform origin to `50% 0` so that the elements scale  from the top.